# Let $B = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : |z_1| \leq |z_2| \}$. Show that B is balanced, but that its interior is not.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the following definitions.

The interior $E^o$ of $E$ is the union of all open sets that are subsets of $E$.

A set $B \subset X$ is said to be balanced if $\alpha B \subset B$ for every $\alpha \in \Phi$ ($\Phi$ is real or complex scalars). With $|\alpha| \leq 1$

My proof to show $B$ is balanced seems okay, but I'm not sure if my proof for the interior not being balanced is sound.

$proof:$

Let $x \in B = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : |z_1| \leq |z_2| \}$, $\alpha \in \Phi$ such that $|\alpha| \leq 1$. Then for $x = (z_1, z_2)$ we have $|z_1| \leq |z_2|$ hence for $\alpha x$ we have $|\alpha||z_1| \leq |\alpha||z_2| \Leftrightarrow |\alpha z_1| \leq |\alpha z_2|$. Thus $\alpha x \in B$, x arbitrary chosen implies $\alpha B \subset B$ and B is balanced.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. then the point $(\epsilon, 0) \notin B$, and therefore the point $(0,0) \notin B^o$ $\Rightarrow$ if $\alpha = 0 \leq 1$ and $x\in B^o$ $\alpha x \notin B^o$. Therefore $B^o$ is not balanced.

Any kind of conformation or critiques are welcome and appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set:
$$B:=\{|z|\leq|z'|\}$$

It is balanced since:
$$(z,z')\in B:\quad|\lambda z|=|\lambda|\cdot|z|\leq|\lambda|\cdot|z'|=|\lambda z'|\quad(|\lambda|\leq1)$$

Consider its interior:
$$B°=\{|z|<|z'|\}$$

It is not balanced since:
$$(1,2)\in B°:\quad|0\cdot1|=|0|=0\nless0=|0|=|0\cdot2|\quad(|0|\leq1)$$

Comment: My only issue is that the interior is a union of all open subsets of B just because this particular subset is not balanced why does that make the entire union unbalanced?

Comment: @Ben: If you have a balanced set and another set then their union doesn't need to be balanced again. *(Is this your issue?)*

Comment: Essentially yes.